# LotusNotes Sametime interferes with VPN connection(and vice versa). Supposed fix online doesn't address it?

Tags: sametime

We're having issues using a VPN connection and SameTime chat at the same time(pun intended).

There was a supposed fix here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21433381

It says :

> For earlier versions, a hotfix JLII-85NPC3 has been developed to
>   disable the network monitor in conjunction with the
>   rcpinstall.properties setting:
>
> ```
> -Dcom.lotus.sametime.core.util.connection.NetworkMonitorInterval=-1
> ```

But for some reason, it's not working, even though I'm supposed to have sametime 8.5.

Any tips on this are appreciated.